# Byte Offset of FLV keyframes for netStream.appendBytes()

Tags: c, actionscript-3, flv, flash-video

**Short Version:**

I am looking for a library or sample code in either C or Actionscript which allows me to find the byte offset in a FLV file for each keyframe. I am aware that the spec is published at http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf but wading through it and writing reliable code would, hopefully, be reinventing the wheel ;)

**Longer version:**

In Actionscript- I am successfully using netStream.appendBytes() to play a flv file. However, now I want to enable seeking.

It seems that I must change the stream offset to the beginning of a keyframe in the file, simply seeking to any position in the file does not work (neither when using NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_SEEK nor NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN)

However, I'm not sure how to determine where that is. Even if the file were encoded with CBR and I knew the timecode for a keyframe, it would still need to be after the header which could be any length.

So I am looking for a library or solution in either C or Actionscript which allows me to find the byte offset in the file of each keyframe- that way I'll have the precise value and can even use VBR

(C will be used either to find this information beforehand, or possibly at runtime via alchemy)

Comment: Have You checked onSeekPoint event ? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onSeekPoint

Comment: Wow- I have not... I would hug you if I could, but at the very least- please re-submit your suggestion as an answer so I can mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use netStream onSeekPoint event :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onSeekPoint

Comment: Awesome, though I'm wondering if there is a solution which doesn't require loading through netstream, i.e. more purely from straight file reading